When transferring BTC, and it is stalled with the message "untreated" what does that mean?
I have $274.97 in an account with BCRPRO that I need to withdraw after making several attempted transfers to first cashapp,after it read successful operation it was reversed back into the BCRPRO account. I attempted to send it to my bank, it too said successful but was back in the original account.  It was restricted for 72hrs. And I was told by BCRPRO it would cost me $200 to withdraw $274.before the restriction is lifted. I spoke to support at coinbase where the funds will be received that everything is good to accept the payment. As well did support at cash app. Unfortunately cust.support at BCRPRO has not answered any of the many emails I've sent asking what UNTREATED means.Please I can not afford a loss of this amount of money. Does someone know the meaning of UNTREATED and how do I remove this status to be able to complete the transfer into my coinbase account safely.
